# Vb.net project save not opening from anywhere by its original source

Tags: vb.net

[image]

I've made a program for my assingment, and code it entirely from home. Obviously I need to submit it and work on it from college, i've got about 13 hours until it's due and I cannot for the life of me figure out what these errors mean, I'm guessing its something to do with the paths of the files. To make it clear, the program does not open and it is not the original copy. I do have other copies and I have tried the same approach with the exact same luck. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Okay, an update. As I said, I copied it from home, and pasted it in the folder location that it is calling below, however, it's calling an older version of the game which has no relevence to the game(number guessing game), from a location two files up from the actual vb files. Is there a way i can change what the project opens?

[image]

Comment: Do the files exist at those locations? My guess is you've copied the solution file but not the Game.vb files? Screenshotting the relevant folders may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second picture just drag 'Form1.vb' to the solution Explorer. That way it can recognize your form. I have encountered this problem before and I just did what I said above.

Comment: I'm going to mark your answer as correct, though the code is not showing. I'm going to investigate it further when i get home instead. Thanks for trying though man.

Comment: No but I'm figuring that something just didint transfer when copied for whatever reason, there's no way for me to tell at the moment until i get home.